# Medieval (15th and 16th century) records in Spain

Tags: records, spain, 15th-century, 16th-century

In recent meanderings through my family history, we have found a link to medieval (15th and 16th century) Spain ([Pamplona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pamplona) region to be precise) - so, is it possible to access records (births, deaths and marriages) from that region, from that time?

Answer (score 4):

Pamplona is in the region of Navarra and so you will need to search for records from this region. [Family Search](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2brecord_country:Spain%20%2brecord_subcountry:%22Spain,Navarra%22) has quite a lot from this time period and is regularly adding more.

Spanish records, in my experience, are normally very good with more information than you find in some other countries. You also need to be aware of naming conventions, the child of a marriage will take the mothers maiden name as their second surname so if Fred Smith and Emma Jones have a child it would be called Jane Smith Jones or Jane Jones Smith. Jones in the childs' case is not her middle name it is her second surname. This helps in tracking the maternal line back through the generations (this naming is common to male and female descendants).

Comment: Be careful! you have used portugues namings and not spanish. Portugues will be Jane Jones Smith or Mike Jones Smith (in former times, Mike Smith Jones), in Spain will normally be Jane Smith Jones and Mike Smith Jones.

Comment: @TrebiaProject. Are you (or Colin) able to provide an authoritative reference for the name order that you cite?

Comment: @PolyGeo talking about Spain until sXIX that practice (1st paternal name, 2nd maternal name) was not regularized by law and it was a good practice. Only statistical information can be provided. Since 2011 (law 20/2011 raplacing 1957 law) there has been a regulation not providing specific preference to paternal line in the order.